# An internal error occurred during: "Launching <My_APP>". ATTR_EXCLUDE_TEST_CODE

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, eclipse-plugin

I am building a spring boot application in Eclipse and i am getting below error while launching run/debug configuration.

> An internal error occurred during: "Launching ApplicationName MainClassName".
>   ATTR_EXCLUDE_TEST_CODE

i tried deleting app and import as maven project then also same error.
Could any one please help me on this?

Using : Eclipse oxygen, java 8, STS plugin installed, spring boot 2.1.4 Jars

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? Any workarounds? I m facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

exactly same issue with me. struggling with this from last 2 days